# Representing a collection of models in Java MVC (with SWT)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swt

In C#, there are observable collections. In Java how do I represent a list a models? Suppose I have a model `Item`. I want to show users a list of `Items`. Do I create a `ItemsModel` (notice plural, encapsulating an `ArrayList<Item>`) then in my `ItemsView` bind (listen to property change events) to that? This model will also need to listen to PropertyChange events from its underlying `Item`. Is this the right way of implementing this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could be the Eclipse Databinding. It let's you create a binding from your POJOs to certain SWT Controls. For your special case with Items, you could use the Master-Detail Binding mechanism, for an example see http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Data_Binding/Snippets#Master_Detail

Comment: I am using SWT is it different from JFace?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the source of your domain model, you could consider changing it to use Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF). EMF have complete a notification framework for all changes made to the model, which makes it easy to use and bind to. Eclipse Databinding - as mentioned by Tom Seidel - also bind to EMF.